# Posting image does not show up on wall

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using the Facebook IOS library.  I am trying to post an image to the user's wall.  I am able to upload the image to the application Album, but i can not get it to show up on the user's wall.

The application is granted the publish_stream permissions:

```
[self.facebook authorize: [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"publish_stream"]];
```

The image is posted with the following code:

```
NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image), @"source", 
                                   message, @"message", nil];

[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath: @"me/photos"
                          andParams: params
                      andHttpMethod: @"POST"
                        andDelegate: self];
```

This works great - the image end up in the app album on Facebook - now how do I get this image to show up on the user's wall?

Thanks

Greg

Comment: It turns out that this does work in some cases.  If I use an iPad to post the picture, when using the Facebook app on the same iPad the picture is visible on the user's wall.  If I use another device (iPhone or computer/browser) it is not visible on the well, just in Photo's-Albums.

Comment: i think its show a status message once you started to upload other images in your album.